# Statement that is true for all definable sets but not true in general

Tags: set-theory

I am searching for an $\in$-formula $\phi(x)$ with the following property:
For every unary predicate $p(y)$ we have $$ZFC \vdash \forall y (y \in x \leftrightarrow p(y) ) \to \phi(x), \tag{$\ast$}$$
but $$ZFC \not\vdash \phi(x).$$
What I'm hoping to express with this is: Whenever the predicate $p$ defines a set $x$, then $\phi(x)$ holds, but $\phi$ does not hold in general.

The only idea I had so far was to let $\phi$ express the contiuum hypothesis but the proof I had in mind used the wrong intuition, that the constructible universe $L$ contained all definable sets, namely that $$ZFC \vdash \exists x \forall y (y \in x \leftrightarrow p(y) ) \to \exists x (x \in L \land \forall y (y \in x \leftrightarrow p(y) )).$$

Moreover if I understand the fact 'There are models of $ZFC$ which are pointwise definable' correctly there won't be a property formula $\phi$ such that $(\ast)$ holds an additionally $ZFC \vdash \exists x \neg \phi(x)$.
I would very much appreciate if someone could help me find such a formula. Since I've only had minimal exposition to axiomatic set theory there is a chance that this question does not really make sense at all.

Comment: $x$ is ordinal-definable?

Comment: (Also, given your incorrect (but not unreasonable) intuition that every definable set is constructible, why not use the predicate $x\in L$? Not sure where you were going with the continuum hypothesis (that's a sentence not a predicate) but it's overcomplicated at least.)

Comment: Ah right, that would have been even simpler. By continuum hypothesis I meant the formula $x\leq \aleph_0 \lor 2^{\aleph_0}\leq x$.

Comment: ah I see. That’s not necessarily true though. What’s true is that this holds relative to L.

Comment: (I mean it holds relative to $L$ for every $x\in L$, which is different from it simply holding for every $x\in L.$ In other words, it's true that any constructible set is either *constructibly* countable or *constructibly* larger than or equal to in size to the *constructible* reals. On the other hand there will always be constructible sets that have size $\aleph_1$ (e.g. $\aleph_1$ itself), which will be counterexamples to the CH if CH fails.)

Comment: Ok I think I see the problem. I initially thought that $ZF \vdash x \in V \to x \leq \aleph_0 \lor 2^{\aleph_0}  \leq x$ was true, but the problem is that the powerset operation is not absolute with respect to the surrounding universe. Beeing constructibly countable should be fine though though right?

Comment: Assume you meant $x\in L$. Neither $\le$ nor the power set are absolute. Actually $\le$ is absolute outwards, so it's true that if $x\in L$ then $|x| \le \aleph_0$ or $|x|\ge |P^L(\omega)|$ and all that's making the statement false is the power set. But it's consistent that $|P^L(\omega)|=\aleph_0,$ so there could be situations where this isn't saying much. Relativizing $\le$ as well gives us the additional info that the injections witnessing $\le$ are constructible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! This cleared up some confusions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\phi(x)$ say that $x$ is [ordinal-definable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_definable_set), which is first-order expressible and capturable in $\sf ZF$ using the [reflection theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_principle). If a set is definable without parameters, it is certainly definable with ordinal parameters.

And $\sf V =OD$ is not provable in $\sf ZFC$. Lots of forcing extensions serve as countermodels. For instance, adding any number of Cohen reals.

Your statement at the end that the existence of pointwise-definable models make it impossible (barring inconsistency) to find such a predicate that will be provably violated is correct.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this is the best possible answer, in the following sense: if $\phi$ is any formula with the required property, then $\forall x\big( x\in\sf{OD}\implies\phi(x)\big).$  After all, $\sf{OD}$ has a definable well-ordering $<_\sf{OD}.$ So if there were any $x\in\sf{OD}$ such that $\neg\phi(x),$ then there would be a $<_\sf{OD}$-least such $x.$ But that would give a definition of that $x,$ so $\phi(x)$ must hold, and that's a contradiction.

Comment: @MitchellSpector I was thinking about appending something about why $L$ doesn’t work, which is just this argument (plus that V=OD is consistent with V$\ne $L) but your way of framing it is better

Comment: What do you mean "the standard Cohen model"?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Say, add any number of Cohen reals to $L.$

Comment: Thanks. That's clearer. There's a lot of things called "Cohen model", and it wasn't clear to me which one you'd meant.